# How do I make two echo statements subtract in PHP?

Tags: php

I am a newbie in PHP, i wanted to subtract two php echo statement but i get 0 as the result.

These are the echo statements;

```
echo number_format($row_sum['total_amount'], 2, ".", ",");  

echo $row['amount_allocated'];
```

This is the result code bringing zero(0);

```
echo $row['amount_allocated'] - number_format($row_sum['total_amount'], 2, ".", ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of `number_format` is a string, not a number -- you can't use a number with commas in arithmetic. Do the subtraction first, then format the result:

```
$amt_remaining = $row['amount_allocated'] - $row_sum['total_amount'];
echo number_format($amt_remaining, 2, ".", ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the subtraction within the number format function.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound right at all. I think what you want is this:

`echo number_format($row['amount_allocated'] - $row_sum['total_amount'], 2, ".", ",");`

So you apply the formatting to the result of the subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for your contribution which gave me ideas to a solution.

According to Barmar and Blake A. Nichols i removed the commas in the arithmetics then assigned variables as follows:

$a = $row_sum['total_amount'];
$b = $row['amount_allocated'];

did the formatting when echoing the results:

echo number_format($b - $a, 2, ".", ",");